# How to print this ajax text in selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate Snapdeal website.

Steps  followed:

1. `SnapdealHome->Hover` on `Computer&Gaming->Storage->Select` 1TB and 16gb both.
2. Then I want to print what all does the Capacity filter contains.
3. I tried this `xpath` but it doesn't show anything.
4. Is this an ajax code?
5. I want to print what all does the `capacity.getText()` contains.
6. These are the `xpath`s I tried:
   `$x("//div[@class='navFiltersPill'][contains(text(),'Capacity:')]")` and `$x("//div[@class='navFiltersPill']")`.
7. Output should be: 1TB and 16GB both. Is it possible?

[Check the below attached figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24HzT.png)

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to print what all the texts is included in the Capacity.      Ex:if I select 1TB, The capacity text should be 1TB and then when i select 16GB also, then capacity.getText()  should show 16gb as well as 1TB. I am using the getText() to check what all it contains

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use findElements with below xpath and then retrieve the text by looping all matching elements one by one. This will specifically list out all the filtered conditions under **Capacity filter** section. Change the below *data-name* value in the xpath according to your requirement.

```
//div[@data-name='Capacity_s'][contains(@class,'filter-inner filter-inner-height')]/div[contains(@class,'active-filter')]/label/a
```

Sample code: [Make sure to add wait before hitting this line]

```
List<WebElement> ele=d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-name='Capacity_s'][contains(@class,'filter-inner filter-inner-height')]/div[contains(@class,'active-filter')]/label/a"));
    for (WebElement e:ele){
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through all the checked INPUTs and print their `value`. For example,

```
for (WebElement e : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[checked]")))
{
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

will print

```
1%20TB
16GB
```

The `%20` is a space.